# Difference between the topological entropy and Hausdorff dimension for multifractal formalism

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I have been reading some results about multifractal formalism. I noticed that some results were proved for the Hausdorff dimension and some results for the topological entropy (in the sense of Bowen). I am familiar with both definitions, which are similar to each other, but I don't have any images of them in mind or a good intuition of them. Could you give me a good intuition or image about them? Thanks in advance.

For instance, we consider the following system: Let $T:\Sigma \to \Sigma$ be a topologically mixing subshift of finite type and $f:\Sigma \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Holder continuous function. Let $K_\alpha$ be the set where $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}S_{n}f(x)$ exists and is equal to $\alpha$. I want to know how I should imagine $h_{\text{top}}(K_{\alpha})$ and $\dim_{H}(K_{\alpha})$ in my mind.

Comment: The version of $h_\text{top}$ that I am most familiar with is applied to compact sets $K$. In that case in the shift setting, it is just the exponential growth rate of the number of blocks: if $c(n)$ denotes the number of blocks of length $n$ that appear in $K$, $h_\text{top}(K)$ is just the limit of $\frac 1n\log c(n)$. That is, $c(n)\approx e^{h_\text{top}n}$. I believe this is very close to a box dimension. On the other hand, your $K_\alpha$'s are not closed. As you probably know, Hausdorff dimension is bounded above by box dimension because you are have much more freedom in your covers

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.04394 I believe this is relevant

Comment: @AnthonyQuas  Thank you very much

Comment: @VilleSalo Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

The following doesn't necessarily answer your question about how to intuitively interpret entropy and dimension, but it does address the relationship between them, at least in the symbolic setting.

In a one-sided shift space -- whether or not it is an SFT -- topological entropy (in the sense of Bowen's 1973 paper) is identical to Hausdorff dimension, at least up to a scaling constant. The reason for this is that in one-sided shift spaces, metric balls (which are used in the definition of Hausdorff dimension) are identical to dynamical/Bowen balls (which are used in the definition of topological entropy). Indeed, if the metric is defined by $d(x,y) = \theta^n$, where $\theta\in (0,1)$ is a fixed parameter and $n=n(x,y)$ is the smallest index such that $x_n \neq y_n$, then given any $x$ in the shift space and any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, if we write $w = x_1 \cdots x_n$ then the cylinder $[w]$ coincides with both the metric ball $B(x,r)$ for any $r\in (\theta^{n+1},\theta^n]$, and the Bowen ball $B_n(x,\epsilon)$ for any $\epsilon \in (\theta^2,\theta]$. Using this fact you can work directly from the definitions of topological entropy and Hausdorff dimension and quickly show that they agree (up to multiplication by $|\log\theta|$ or some constant like that).

I believe this is all described in the paper by Stephen Simpson that Ville Salo's comment linked to, but it seemed worth spelling out the main parts of the story here.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate it.

Comment: Vaughn: can I get you to expand your helpful answer here to address a possible confusion of mine. In my comment on the q, I was suggesting that topological entropy is closer to box dimension than Hausdorff dimension, since with topological entropy you're essentially covering by cylinders all of the same length. Am I missing something? Or is there a reason that for these dynamical sets, Hausdorff dimension and box dimension agree?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas , it goes back to Furstenberg, in his seminal Disjoinetness paper, where he showed that for 1-sided subshifts, the Minkowski dimension and Hausdorff dimension coincide. Now the question is about how good of an encoding one gets.

Comment: Anthony: There's some ambiguous terminology at work here. The most common use of the term "topological entropy" is indeed as you describe: count the number of cylinders/Bowen balls all of the same order, then take the growth rate as that order increases. And in a shift space, that quantity is proportional to the box/Minkowski dimension by exactly the reasoning in my answer. But Bowen's 1973 TAMS paper introduced a different definition of topological entropy, analogous to Hausdorff dimension, which is given not as a growth rate but as a critical parameter...

Comment: ... that is, given $h\geq 0$ and a subset $Z$ of the shift space you define $m_h(Z) = \lim_{N\to\infty} \inf \sum_{w\in E} e^{|w|h}$, where the infimum is over all collections $E$ of finite words with the property that $Z \subset \bigcup_{w\in E} [w]$. Then the topological entropy ("in the sense of Bowen" as some people write) is the unique value of $h$ at which $m_h(Z)$ jumps from $\infty$ to $0$.

Comment: If $Z$ is compact and shift-invariant then the two definitions of topological entropy agree. But in general they can take different values, as you know well by considering Hausdorff and box dimension.

Comment: Thanks Vaughn!!